# WebAssembly: compilation of loops with return values not behaving as expected

Tags: webassembly

I'm writing a WebAssembly bytecode analyser and came across some behaviour with how various WebAssembly compilers treat loop instructions that I'm finding difficult to reconcile with the WebAssembly specification.

The following snippet (taken from the [WebAssembly loop test cases](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/loop.wast)) shows a nested loop that is expected to return an i32 integer.

```
(module
  (type $t0 (func (result i32)))
  (func $cont-inner (export "cont-inner") (type $t0) (result i32)
    (local $l0 i32)
    i32.const 0
    local.set $l0
    local.get $l0
    loop $L0 (result i32)
      loop $L1 (result i32)
        br $L0
      end
    end
    i32.add
    local.set $l0
```

A visual analysis of the above suggests that this syntax does not strictly conform to the specification (as I understand it) as the body of the loops do not have any stack values to return.

Of course the above loops form an infinite loop and so at execution time the program will not actually exit the outermost loop.

But several of the compilers I have tried compile this without any issues e.g. webassembly.studio. Conversely if the unconditional branch is replaced with a conditional branch then the compilers actually behave as I expect and complain of a missing return value.

Have I missed something in the WebAssembly specification of how loops operate? Or are compilers implicitly doing some reachability analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing is the [stack becoming polymorphic](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/valid/instructions.html#polymorphism) after an unconditional branch. This means that the the stack behaves as if it has the values required to validate.

In this case, the `br $L0` instruction makes the stack polymorphic. Normally falling off the end `loop $L1` would require an `i32` on the stack, but since the stack is polymorphic, the type-checker behaves as if this is true.

You might find the [validation algorithm in the spec](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/appendix/algorithm.html#validation-algorithm) useful.  I also wrote about [WebAssembly type-checking a while back](https://binji.github.io/posts/webassembly-type-checking/), that might be a helpful resource for you.

Comment: Wow, I completely wasn't aware of the concept of the stack becoming polymorphic. That explains a lot in this example and some of the other scenarios I've seen in the WASM test cases involving unconditional branches. Thanks for the resources as well!